# Fortran-Segmentation Fault Upon Closing an Input File

Tags: io, fortran, modeling, numerical

Hopefully, someone can help me out with this problem. It would be greatly appreciated.

Background. I am working on extending a piece of Legacy code for our research group that does some heat transfer, thermal convection, etc. type of numerical modeling. What I am trying to do is read in a temperature input file so that I can adjust the temperature of the model as it model progresses in time. While that info is largely irrelevant. I keep getting a segmentation fault upon trying to close a file I opened and am reading from. I have attached the code below along with what a typical temperature input file may look like (but greatly simplified since there will be thousands of data points). Any help would be appreciated in eliminating the segmentation fault and/or correcting the code to make it more efficient.

```
subroutine Read_Temp_Input(Temp_in)!(dt)!(filename)!,dt,Temp_out)
implicit none

character*80                                :: filename
integer, parameter                          :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
real(kind=dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:)  :: Temp_in, Temp_out
integer                                     :: i,j,ierror,n
real (kind=dp)                              :: in_time, in_temp, dt, inter_time, inter_temp, max_time
character*80                                :: line


!Variable definitions
!in_time is the time given from the input file
!in_temp is the temp given from the input file
!inter_time is the interpolated time using dt, max_time, and linear interpolation
!inter_temp is the interpolated temp using dt, max_time, and linear interpolation
!max_time is the largest time value in the input file
!dt is the time step utilized in the simulation, provided by main routine

!read in the temperature input file
filename = "temps.txt"
Open(UNIT=1,FILE=filename,ACTION="Read")

!Determine the size of the necessary allocation
n = 0
do
    Read(1,*,iostat=ierror) in_time, in_temp
    if (ierror.ne.0) then
        exit
    else
        print*, in_time, in_temp
        n = n + 1
    endif
enddo

!Allocate the Temp_in array to a n x 2 array.
allocate(Temp_in(n,2))

close(unit=1)
Open(UNIT=1,FILE=filename,ACTION="Read")

n = 0

do
    Read(1,*,iostat=ierror) in_time, in_temp
    if (n.ne.0) then
        if (ierror.ne.0) then
            exit
        else
            Temp_in(n-1,0) = in_time
            Temp_in(n-1,1) = in_temp
        endif
    endif
    n = n + 1
enddo

dt = 0.5_dp
print*, 'is the fault before here?'
close(1)
print*, 'is the fault here?'
end subroutine
```

Temperature File

```
 Time  Temp
 1     300
 2     400
 3     500
 5     600
```

Attached is also an output I have been getting. I will get rid of the random print statements in time, just using them as a way to test where my code is breaking.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsTfe.png)

Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you compiled your code with the various debugging options your compiler offers?  If you haven't, I'd be very worried about the line `Temp_in(n-1,0) = in_time`.  Your compiler should certainly be checking for bounds issues.

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem at hand: first the code reads the input file line-by-line to figure out how many lines there are (ie to get a value for `n` to allocate `temp_in`).  So far so good, now the code knows how many data points to read.  Then, to my surprise, the code uses the same strategy to read the data points, ie it reads the input file line-by-line, checking for the end of file at each turn, and explicitly incrementing `n` again.  Surely the second loop could start `do i = 1,n` ?

Comment: Do not copy outputs or code as images. When you really have to do that, than at least enter the damn image description. Bot don't do that, copy everything here **as text**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortran arrays are 1-based by default, and so is `Temp_in` in your example. So the lines

```
Temp_in(n-1,0) = in_time
Temp_in(n-1,1) = in_temp
```

will write out of bounds (for `n=1`, both are out of bounds and the first one is always out of bounds).

You can make the compiler check that for you by using the `--check=bounds` flag, it will then throw a runtime error if you attempt to access an array in that manner.

So either allocate `Temp_in` as

```
 allocate(Temp_in(0:n-1,0:1))
```

or use 1-based indices for writing as a solution.

---

**UPDATE**

Also, reading the first line of the example `temps.txt` file will fail when determining the number of entries, as it tries to read two `real` but instead finds something else. So you will need to do a dummy read after opening the file to read in the first line (or use the same additional check as in the second loop)

```
Open(UNIT=1,FILE=filename,ACTION="Read")
! read in the first line and throw it away
read(1,*)
! go on
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have changed the allocation to the way you recommended. However, I am still getting the segmentation error. Also, I am aware that the first line will be read in as error, reading a string as a real, and the one I have the if statements set up, allow for me to basically skip that row and read the succeeding rows into the array. Additionally, I should note that if I print out values from the array they are correct. Leading me to believe that the array allocation is working but the error is somehow popping up with closing the input file. Thanks again.

Comment: Update: I somehow at typed a -1 instead of 0 in the error checking line. Fixing that with your allocation method seems to have done the trick. Thank you every much for your help.